# how to run the same function with button and multiselect box in Angular

Tags: angular

Im new in programming and especially web. I have a MultiSelect box, it plot a line chart upon a selecting an item, for example you select n number of items and you can see n number of lines on the chart, next to it there are two date pickers which shows (From and To) by default its from yesterday to Today. It works fine, now the problem is if user selects n number of items and wants to change the date range should press a filter button to apply the changes; I don't how to make this button execute the same code as my multi select changed handler.

Here is my checkbox value changed function:

```
 public valueChange(value: string): void {
  this.from = formatDate(this.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en_US');
  this.to = formatDate(this.value1, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en_US');

  if (this.temp.length < value.length) {
     console.log('seleted');
     this.Legendtemp.push(value);
     this.serisName = value;
     this.services.getWindAverage(value, this.from, this.to).subscribe(s => {
        this.selected = s;
        this.series.push(this.selected);
        i = this.series.length - 1;
     });
     this.temp.push(value.length);
  } else {
     console.log('Dseleted');
     if (this.temp.length != 0) {
        this.temp.pop();
        this.selected.pop();
        this.temp.length;
     }
  }
}
```

valuChange is the multiselectBox function and value is the selected items. getWindAverage is my service which pass date along with selected items to the backend to get the result,now how should my button work? here is its function

```
onFilter(){}
```

here is my template:

```
        <div class="card"  style="margin: 0 Auto;width: 1200px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <kendo-multiselect style="width: 50%;"  [data]="rslt"  [textField]="'turbine_name'"  [valueField]="'turID'"  (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" [valuePrimitive]="true" placeholder="Select a Turbine..." >
        </kendo-multiselect>
      <label>From:</label>
      <kendo-datepicker (valueChange)="onchange()" [(value)]="value"  format="dd/MM/yyyy"></kendo-datepicker>
      <label>To:</label>
      <kendo-datepicker format="dd/MM/yyyy" [(value)]="value1"></kendo-datepicker> 
      <button type="button"  (click)="onFilter()"  class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px;"  >Filter</button>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the template of the component? We can only assume that `this.value` and `this.value1` are public properties on your component that are bound using `ngModel` to the date pickers in the template, but it is also useful to see if the multi select is also bounded to some property, this way you can create a function that uses the bound properties and call it everywhere you need (on the multi select value changed handler, and also on the button click handler).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the Kendo UI for Angular, it looks like the controls you are using have support for the `ngModel` directive, but in order for this to work, you need to make sure you have the `FormsModule` imported in the module that declares the component you mentioned (having a module imported means that it should be placed in the `imports` array).

After importing the `FormsModule` you can come back to the template you just posted and do something like this:

HTML:

```
  <div class="card" style="margin: 0 Auto;width: 1200px;">
     <div class="card-body">
        <kendo-multiselect
                          style="width: 50%;"
                          [data]="rslt"
                          textField="turbine_name"
                          valueField="turID"
                          (valueChange)="onMultiSelectValueChanged()"
                          [(ngModel)]="selectedTurbines"
                          name="selectedTurbines"
                          [valuePrimitive]="true"
                          placeholder="Select a Turbine...">
        </kendo-multiselect>
        <label>From:</label>
        <kendo-datepicker (valueChange)="onchange()" [(value)]="value" format="dd/MM/yyyy"></kendo-datepicker>
        <label>To:</label>
        <kendo-datepicker format="dd/MM/yyyy" [(value)]="value1"></kendo-datepicker>
        <button type="button" (click)="onFilter()" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px;">Filter</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

In order for this to work properly, you also need to do some work in your `.ts` file:

```
  value: string;
  value1: string;
  selectedTurbines: string[] = [];

  onMultiSelectValueChanged() {
     this.plotChart();
  }

  onFilter() {
     this.plotChart();
  }

  private plotChart() {
     this.from = formatDate(this.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en_US');
     this.to = formatDate(this.value1, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en_US');

     if (this.temp.length < this.selectedTurbines.length) {
        console.log('seleted');
        this.Legendtemp.push(this.selectedTurbines);
        this.serisName = this.selectedTurbines;
        this.services.getWindAverage(this.selectedTurbines, this.from, this.to).subscribe(s => {
           this.selected = s;
           this.series.push(this.selected);
           i = this.series.length - 1;
        });
        this.temp.push(this.selectedTurbines.length);
     } else {
        console.log('Dseleted');
        if (this.temp.length != 0) {
           this.temp.pop();
           this.selected.pop();
           this.temp.length;
        }
     }
  }
```

So basically what I did extra is to bind the value of the multi select to a property in the component, and also move the logic used to build the plot into a new function that does not depend on the selected turbines directly, but instead it uses the bound property to access them. This way you can call this code from the multi select change handler and from the button click handler. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Do not forget to add the `name` attribute on the multi select that has the `ngModel` directive on it, or else you will get a console error about it.